# Yii - How to insert a placeholder in the dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-extensions

I'm new to Yii framework. I created dropdownlists using the below code -

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'min_cost', Yii::app()->params['cost_resales']);
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'max_cost', Yii::app()->params['cost_resales']);
```

Now, I cannot insert a place holder, in the above dropdownlists. I tried using the below htmloptions to insert placeholder

```
array('empty'=>'Min')
array('empty'=>'Max')
```

This works fine. But , this values get included in dropdownlist also. I don't want them to be included in dropdownlist.
I'm using the below Jquery code to populate the dropdownlist values.

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){ 
   // Keep a copy of the default options
    var $options = jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost').children().clone();


    jQuery('#SearchForm_min_cost').change(function(){

    // Within your change handler:

        var index = jQuery(this).find(':selected').index();
        jQuery('#SearchForm_max_cost').html($options).children(':lt('+index+')').remove();

    }); 

});
</script>
```

How can I not include this values along with the list. I want them to be as placeholder and not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`CHtml.dropDownList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#dropDownList-detail) docs, you can specify a `prompt` in the htmlOptions array. This will show up but won't be selectable. Perhaps that's what you really wanted?

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'min_cost',Yii::app()->params['cost_resales'],array(
    'prompt'=>'Please select the minimum value',
));
```

Comment: How so? I've added an example to my answer. Care to try that one out?

Comment: I added it and even it is displayed in the list. I can see `Please select the minimum value` included inthe list.

Comment: Can I do something with the css properties

Comment: Hardly. If it's part of the list, it's part of the list. But I get a feeling you don't really know what you want.

Comment: I don't want that to be included in the selection list. This should only be displayed in the box.

Comment: Can't be done. Unless you're rendering HTML outside the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder is a text which is shown if a text field is empty similarly in select field you cant add placeholder directly you have to choose an empty option value which will remain selected at first so you have to use

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'min_cost',Yii::app()->params['cost_resales'],array(
'empty'=>'Please select the minimum value',
```

));

While using this you will get your placeholder in select.